# Can't select text in RichEditComponent control

Tags: c#, wpf, hwnd, owner

I want to keep my app's window in front of another programs's window.
My app is created with WPF, I set owner with another window's hwnd like this:

```
// this: my wpf window   
WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);

//The hwnd is handle of window that other program I want to follow    
helper.Owner = new IntPtr(hwnd);
```

Everything is perfect, but I can't select text with mouse within RichEditComponent of the window (the hwnd window).

Any idea to fix this?

---

Don't know other program write with which language,maybe c++. Handle of other program's window obtained with windows api "FindWindowEx".

Comment: Your screen capture is not very useful. Some text seems to be selected ?

Answer (score 0):

If your *other* program is a Winforms program, you need to add a reference to

> `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.dll`

and add a call to [`ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(Window window)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.enablemodelesskeyboardinterop?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_Integration_ElementHost_EnableModelessKeyboardInterop_System_Windows_Window_) like shown below:

```
WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
helper.Owner = new IntPtr(hwnd);

ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(this);
```

because apparently Winforms and WPF have different ways of handling text input (and therefore also affecting text selection - more specific, copy & paste of selected text - as well).

---

Other than that, the issue might be the HWND pointer - how do you obtain it?

- e.g. this is how you can obtain the main window handle by specifying a process name:

  ```
  Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("...")[0];
  IntPtr hwnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Don't know other program write with which language,maybe c++. The method you post can't work.Handle of other program's window obtained with windows api "FindWindowEx".

Comment: @cqsir it should still work though. Nevertheless, did you try the approach with `ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop`?

Comment: public void SetOwner(Window wnd, int hwnd)
        {
            if (wnd == null) return;

            WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(wnd);
            helper.Owner = new IntPtr(hwnd);

            ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wnd);
            //WindowsFormsHost.EnableWindowsFormsInterop();
        }

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved the question by detect Mouse drag event use global hook. When drag start,cancel set owner,and then,when drag finished,set owner with the follow window again.

Use MouseKeyHook to detect global mouse drag event.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MouseKeyHook

Thanks @Thomas Flinkow again,for your help!